# Как можно сохранять сессию после закрытия приложения?

Tags: java, android

Я начал писать клиент для сайта.

Сначала нужно авторизоваться. А после можно пользоваться сайтом.

Я решил, что нужно использовать сессию, чтобы не авторизовываться каждый раз.

Как можно сохранять сессию даже после закрытия приложения?

Какие классы использовать для этого?

Comment: что вы вкладываете в понятие сессии?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko под словом сессия я подразумеваю коробку, в которой хранятся cookies. Как я понял, сайт только по ним определяет авторизован пользователь или нет.

Comment: да, но в android лучше использовать sharedPreferences для таких целей, с дополнительной информацией вы сможете ознакомится в моем ответе ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта простой и сложный но они оба связаны с использованием `SharedPreferences`:

1. Простой - вы записываете в памяти устройства что пользователь был удачно залогинен, например будет переменная `hasVisited`. При удачном входе (пароль и логин верны) вы записываете в память устройства что переменная имеет значение `true`:

   ```
   sp = getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0)
   val editor = sp!!.edit()
   editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", true)
   editor.apply()
   ```

   и дальше в активности с которой стартует приложение мы проверяем эту переменную в функции `onCreate`:

   ```
   val hasVisited: Boolean = sp!!.getBoolean("hasVisited", false)
   if (hasVisited) {
     // переменная равно true и значит можно например через интент перейти на следующий экран
   } else {
     // переменная равна false и значит нужно ввести пароль и логин для авторизации

   }
   ```

вот вариант на java:
в активности в методе `onCreate` нужно записать так:

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

дальше при авторизации вам нужно будет класть переменную в память устройства:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", true).commit;
```

2. Второй способ:
   Создаем класс для работы с настройками приложения:

   public class Session {

   ```
   private SharedPreferences prefs;

   public Session(Context cntx) {
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
   }

   public void setusename(String usename) {
       prefs.edit().putString("usename", usename).commit();
   }

   public String getusename() {
       String usename = prefs.getString("usename","");
       return usename;
   }
   }
   ```

и дальше в активности его используем:

```
private Session session;//global variable 
session = new Session(cntx); //in oncreate 
//and now we set sharedpreference then use this like

session.setusename("USERNAME");
```

и дальше можно после сохранения пароля и логина их оттуда взять, например так:

```
session.getusename();
```

так же я вот есть приблизительный вариант функции выхода из аккаунта:

```
public  void logout(View view){
      SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
      editor.clear();
      editor.commit();
   }
```

оба способа приблизительно одинаковы по исполнению, просто второй немного более запарный на мой взгляд. Надеюсь поможет :)